# Why does $|P_U − P_V |$ equal $\langle \psi |U^{\dagger} M U|\psi\rangle −\langle \psi |V^{\dagger} M V |\psi\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, measurement, nielsen-and-chuang

In QC and QI by Chuang and Nielsen, they state that the $P_U$ of operation $U$ acting on $\psi$ can be reached by $\langle \psi |U^{\dagger} M U |\psi\rangle$.

Where $P_U$ (or $P_V$) is the probability of obtaining the corresponding measurement outcome if the operation $U$ (or $V$). And $M$ is a POVM measurement element.

Then

$$|P_U − P_V | = \langle \psi |U^{\dagger} M U|\psi\rangle −\langle \psi |V^{\dagger} M V |\psi\rangle.$$

This equality appears in the book on page 195 (Box 4.1: Approximating quantum circuits; equation 4.64).

I don't understand it. Can anyone explain it? And why do they equal each other?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) for properly typesetting mathematical expressions and use the [appropriate tags](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags). Go through [How to write a good question?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370). I've [edit]ed it this time.

Comment: What are $P$ and $M$ in your question? That should add some clarity to the question. Also what do you mean by why do they equal each other? Adding a reference to which page of the Nielsen and Chuang are you reading will also be helpful.

Comment: I assume it's equation 4.64 (Box 4.1: Approximating quantum circuits) that you're referring to? (page 195 in the one I've got)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Yes.  Can you please clarify this equality?

Comment: Do you want absolute values on both sides? Neither?

Comment: Don't care about absolute values . I want first to understand it in the most basic way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that outcome $m$ associated with POVM measurement $M$ comes out after measuring state $|\psi\rangle$ can be calculated by:

$p(m)=\langle\psi|M|\psi\rangle$.

The box in the Isaac and Chuang book says that $P_U$ is the probability of such outcome if $U$ operation is applied, and $P_V$ if $V$ is applied. Consequently, we want to calculate such probabilities for states:

- $|\psi_U\rangle=U|\psi\rangle$
- $|\psi_V\rangle=
  V|\psi\rangle$

Applying the definition for calculating such probabilities that I presented at the beginning, then you can obtain what you need:

- $P_U=\langle\psi_U|M|\psi_U\rangle=(U|\psi\rangle)^\dagger MU|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|U^\dagger MU|\psi\rangle$
- $P_V=\langle\psi_V|M|\psi_V\rangle=(V|\psi\rangle)^\dagger MV|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|V^\dagger MV|\psi\rangle$

**EDIT:**

To follow the question you gave in the comment to the answer. Postulate 3 of quantum mechanics states that those are described by a collection of measurement operators $\{M_m\}$ related with each of the outcomes $m$ that the quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ can have. Such postulate does also state that the probability to get outcome $m$ is given by

$p(m)=\langle\psi|M_m^\dagger M_m|\psi\rangle$.

POVM measurements are given by a collection of positive operators $E_m$ that fullfil that $\sum_m E_m=I$. Such operators can be related with the measument operators like

$E_m\equiv M_m^\dagger M_m$.

All this is stated in the Isaac and Chuang book on quantum computation and information that seems that you are using, so refer there for more complete details.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any intuitive/ mathematical way to understand this equality 

p(m)=⟨ψ|M|ψ⟩.???  Or any Link explaining why this is the connection between povm to normal measurements?

Comment: I edited the answer to include what you asked now. I assume that by *normal* measurements you refer to what I was stating.

Comment: Thank you very much. There are still a few things I don't understand here. But you helped me.

Comment: Why when you multply 
⟨ψU|M |ψU⟩  you take the dagger of the first state and U??   The book says this is just a notation for  inner product |ψ>  with   M |ψ⟩.  So why did you take the dagger of the first?  You referred to it as a bra instead of a ket? When the book says it's ket by ket in general

Comment: The bra-ket notation is to refer to vectors in a Hilbert space. Kets are standard complex coumn vectors and their notation is $|\psi\rangle$. Bras refer to the Hermitian transpose vectors of the Kets, so $\langle\psi|=|\psi\rangle^\dagger$. consequently, if your state is $|\psi_U\rangle=U|\psi\rangle$, that is, your ket state transformed by a unitary, then the bra is the Hermitian transpose of all of it, $\langle\psi_U|=|\psi_U\rangle^\dagger=(U|\psi\rangle)^\dagger=|\psi\rangle^\dagger U^\dagger=\langle\psi|U^\dagger$.

Comment: I understand what you say Jous.  But the book says page 62. <ϕ|A|ψ>
 Inner product between |ϕ>
 and A|ψ>
. Which sounds like ket by ket

Comment: Yeah, it is indeed a ket by ket inner product, but the standard inner product in linear algebra is defined as $x \cdot y=x^\dagger y$ if $x$ and $y$ are complex column vectors. That inner product between column vectors is translated then to the bra-ket notation as $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ if $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are quantum states. Remenber that the bra-ket is just a notation of standard linear algebra for QM.

Comment: Haaaa LOL. This is so nice!!! So now I understand also why it's notated like this ⟨ϕ|ψ⟩... I thought its just an arbitrary notation for 'inner product'. And I forgot totally about  x⋅y=x†y.  Now everything is clear of course. Thank you very much. I never got any formal education so I don't remember everything clearly. I study on my own.  Thanks for your time!!

Comment: No problem. If you accepted my answer would be good so that people know that the answer is useful and they can rely on it if they had the same question.

Comment: Ho yeah for sure!